# How to sum values as absolute in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services

I have table where i have sum expression for group value but I want it to sum absolute values. How is it possible to make in ssrs? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are different ways you can accomplish this.

```
=SUM(Fields!Projected.Value) - SUM(Fields!Actual.Value)
```

Another way is it to use the TextBox name where you calculate the difference and then use it to calculate.

```
=SUM(ReportItems!TextBoxDiff.Value)
```

Another way is to get the TextBox names where you aggregate the Projected and Actual values.

```
=ReportItems!TextBoxProjAgg.Value - ReportItems!TextBoxActAgg.Value
```